# Why did those encoded output show in my psql console?

Tags: postgresql, psql, output-formatting

I set up the psqlrc.conf file as follow, but the psql console output looks really weird with unreadable words. Does anyone know what's wrong with my psqlrc.conf file? Do I need to set up the environment to utf-8 in the command line, like `SET PGCLIENTENCODING=utf-8`?

```
**Here is psqlrc.conf file:**
\set ON_ERROR_STOP on
\set HISTCONTROL ignoredups                           
\set COMP_KEYWORD_CASE upper
\set VERBOSITY verbose
-- Output Fomatting
\x auto
\pset linestyle unicode
\pset border 2
\pset format wrapped
\pset pager off
\timing


**Here is psql console output:** 
INSERT 0 87
Time: 613.572 ms
â”Œâ”€[ RECORD 1 ]â”€â”€â”€â”¬â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”
â”‚ time â”‚ 727  â”‚
â”‚ demo_groups    â”‚ 6    â”‚
â”‚ row_count      â”‚ 2124 â”‚
â”œâ”€[ RECORD 2 ]â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤
â”‚ time â”‚ 728  â”‚
â”‚ demo_groups    â”‚ 6    â”‚
â”‚ row_count      â”‚ 2125 â”‚
â”œâ”€[ RECORD 3 ]â”€â”€â”€â”¼â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”¤
```

Comment: It's trying to use Unicode characters to draw lines around your output (because you set `linestyle unicode`) but your terminal program isn't set up to expect Unicode, so it's trying to render the individual bytes in something ASCII-like, probably ISO-8869-1/15, or Cp-1252.

Comment: Thanks, @IMSoP! yeah, it now works as I turned off linestyle unicode in my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

chech your encoding with

```
postgres=> \set
AUTOCOMMIT = 'on'
PROMPT1 = '%/%R%# '
PROMPT2 = '%/%R%# '
PROMPT3 = '>> '
VERBOSITY = 'default'
VERSION = 'PostgreSQL 9.2.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit'
DBNAME = 'postgres'
USER = 'postgres'
PORT = '5432'
ENCODING = 'WIN1252'
```

change the variable ENCODING

```
\set ENCODING
```

Comment: If you check the comments of the question, OP already solves the problem, so if you want to add another solution, please provide more info of what you solution do.. how it does and why it works.